# When using findcirclesgrid() to find the Asymmetric circle grid with angles, the function didn't work

Tags: opencv

The resolution is `2592*1944`, the grid almost fill the image, then the problems comes out. I can find the grid when the board is parallel to the lens, just like that
[image]

When the board is with angles, the function doesn't work:
[image]

Sincerely ask for help, thank you.

Here is my code.

```
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.maxArea = 30000;
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.05f;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> blobDetector = new SimpleBlobDetector(params);
bool found = findCirclesGrid(circleimg, Size(cbCols, cbRows), corners, CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID, blobDetector);
```

Comment: The issue is not clear.. could you post a minimal code so as I can try myself

Comment: Have you tried playing with the parameters?

Comment: Thanks for you guys reply, I had solved the problem. I adjusted the Area parameters and Circularity parameters then using a CLUSTERING flag in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it down as a note for myself, and share my experience.

```
Mat circleimg = imread("circle.bmp");
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.maxArea = 30000;
params.minArea = 1000;
params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 180;
params.thresholdStep = 5;
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minCircularity = 0.7;
params.filterByInertia = false;
params.filterByConvexity = false;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> blobDetector = new SimpleBlobDetector(params);

//this part can be used to test the if the blob detector work.
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
blobDetector->detect(circleimg, keypoints);
Mat circleimg_tmp = circleimg.clone();
for (size_t i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
{
    circle(circleimg_tmp, keypoints[i].pt, 25, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
}
namedWindow("circleimg", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("circleimg", circleimg_tmp);
waitKey(0);

bool found = findCirclesGrid(circleimg, Size(cbCols, cbRows), corners, CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID | CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING, blobDetector);
drawChessboardCorners(circleimg, Size(cbCols, cbRows), corners, found);
imshow("circleimg", circleimg);
```

I found a problem that even the blobdetector find the circle, the findcirclesgrid() function cannot work too, when I'm not using the clustering flag.